# lazy sequence evaluation timing issue

Tags: clojure

I want to expand URLs from Twitter data and (simultaneously-ish) extract their domains. I tried doing this before in Python using requests, but I guess I screwed up somewhere, because the vast majority of the URLs are still in 'short' form (bit.ly, goo.gl, etc.) I've got the Twitter data stored as JSON. I'm using `clj-http.client :as client` to resolve the URLs. I've got code that looks like this, so far:

```
(defn expand-urls [urls] (for [url-str urls] 
                     (and url-str (last (:trace-redirects 
                                          (client/get url-str))))))

(def ^:dynamic *domain-pat* (re-pattern #"https?://([\w\.]+)/.*"))

(defn get-domains [urls] (for [url urls] (first (filter #(not= url %1) 
                           (re-find *domain-pat* url)))))
```

I've got the Twitter data formatted `[tweet-id [{tweet-data-map} {user-data-map}]]`, so `(get-in json-data [1 0 "urls"]` returns the URLs, `(get-in json-data [1 0 "domains"])` returns the domains.

When I try something like `(update-in (update-in js-line [1 0 "urls"] expand-urls) [1 0 "domains"] get-domains)`, `domains` are `(nil)`. I've independently verified that my regex works, so I suspect that the issue is that the lazy sequence returned by `expand-urls` isn't evaluating by the time `get-domains` gets called. Frustratingly, `(type (doall (expand-urls some-urls)))` returns `clojure.lang.LazySeq`, as does `(type (doall (doall (expand-urls some-urls))))`. I've tried `doall`, I've tried adding `vec` into `expand-urls`. Neither seem to work.

Is this really a laziness issue, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Are you binding the result of update-in? update-in does not mutate its argument, it returns a modified copy. Also, consider using `(.getHost (java.net.URL. address))` instead of a regex.

Comment: The way to handle laziness is to use the result of the lazy function. It will remain a lazy seq in type whether realized (ie. via doall) or not.

Comment: Followup to noisesmith's comment: You can used `realized?` to test whether a lazy seq has been realized.

Comment: This doesn't all make sense to me yet.  Here are some comments and questions that might be relevant. About your remark: 'When I try something like (update-in (update-in js-line [1 0 "urls"] expand-urls) [1 0 "domains"] get-domains), domains are (nil).',  What does the word "domains" in that sentence refer to?  Note that `update-in` does not modify its argument `js-line`; it returns a distinct structure that reflects the modifications you wanted.  Don't expect `update-in` to change `js-line`.

Comment: In this kind of situation, if it were me, I would worry that I'm confused about the nested references that I'm trying to get `update-in` to handle.  I would expand that into something more complicated using `let` for example, or play with it at the repl, and figure out the problem that way.  That should make it easier to figure out what's going on, and you can put it back in the nested `update-in` form after that.  At the very least, that would allow you to simplify the question to one that focuses on a more specific problem.

Comment: I should add that I'm VERY new to Clojure. I was under the impression that the inner `update-in` returns a brand-new modified data structure, that then gets passed to the outer one. I come from a Python background, where it's very easy to bind the results of a function to a var and then call another function on it. I still haven't wrapped my head around how to get Clojure to do "two things," as it were. I tried playing around with `let`, but like I said, I'm new and couldn't get it working.

As I clearly didn't explain that well, `"domains"`, like `"urls"`, refers to a key in the inner map.

Comment: `let` is sequential and the bindings nest: `(let [b (f a) c (g b)] ...)` g can use the result of f without having to double nest the function calls

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your solution into

```
(defn expand-urls [urls] (
  (mapv #(last (:trace-redirects (client/get %))
    (remove nil? urls)))
```

assuming you don't want nils in your result. Mapv is the strict counterpart of the lazy map and always returns a vector.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it! The key was adding a `doall` into `expand-urls`:

```
(defn expand-urls [urls] (vec (doall (for [url-str urls]
                       (and url-str (last (:trace-redirects
                                          (client/get url-str))))))))
```

(The `vec` isn't actually necessary, but I'm planning on re-serializing this stuff, and didn't want to worry about how [org.clojure/data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json) translates lists.)

Thanks for the help, everybody! I'm glad there's a vibrant clojure support community here :)

Comment: vec makes the doall redundant, because vectors are an eager datatype. Also, the serializer will be eager, (and will output the same thing for a lazy seq as a vec), so neither the vec or doall is actually needed here.

Comment: this isn't the solution, you solved some problem that is unrelated to this code somewhere else